Regexp for `q.?r` but not `sqrtf`
I need a regexp that matches the characters q and r in sequence, maybe with another character in between, without seeing hits from instances of sqrtf. However sq.?r, q.?rt and q.?rtf are all allowed. How to specify that ?
The closest I got was
(s(?!qrtf))?q.?r

But it seems ()? isn't "greedy", if the term even applies here. It successfully does not hit on sqr in sqrtf, but it does hits on qr in sqrtf because it indeed does not contain s, let alone "s not followed by qrtf".

Should the regex match qar in sqartf?

You can use
q(?<!sq(?=rtf)).?r

See the regex demo.
Details:

q(?<!sq(?=rtf)) - a q letter that is not preceded with s and not followed with an rtf substring
.? - any optional character other than line break characters
r - an r letter.

Another variation of the same idea is (?<!s(?=qrtf))q.?r.

I seem to be missing the concept behind (?=). Care to explain ?

@Charles It is a positive lookahead. It requires a specific pattern to occur immediately to the right of the current location. Since it is used in a negative lookbehind, it will work as AND operation in conjunction with the negative lookbehind. So, "if there is no s AND no q + 1 char + rtf, then match".

Oooooh thank you. And repeating the q inside that part allows us to construct the and part in not preceded by s and not followed by rtf

Is the .? in the lookahead required? that seems like it would exclude matching qar in sqartf. https://regex101.com/r/A6H2hM/1 I've asked OP to clarify whether that should match or not as it isn't really clear from the question.

@Nick Right, looks like there is only one fixed exception.

Yeah, that's how I understand it.

@WiktorStribiżew Can you please review your closure of this question. I think the main problem is how to match a sequence of comma-separated optional items, my updated answer shows how to achieve that. To me the question is about more than just detecting an empty string.
